# How to extend a union type in another module?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is there a way to extend another module's union type?  Below is a contrived example illustrating the need, but I got a ts(3200) duplicate identifier error with the approach.

In the Core module @org/core, there is a union type OptionType:

```js
// In Core module @org/core

export type OptionType = OptionAType | OptionBType;
```

In another module, I want to extend the core module's OptionType to include a new type MyListOptionType.

So when anyone uses `@org/list`, they can use the extended OptionType.

```js
// In ListModule of another package @org/list

import type { OptionType as OriginalOptionType } from '@org/core';

type MyListOptionType = { foo: string; bar: number };

declare module '@org/core' {
  type OptionType = OriginalOptionType | MyListOptionType;
}
```

However, my current approach causes a duplicate identifier error (ts(3200)).

Comment: Even if you *could* do this, it would likely make code in the original module incorrect. The code will be written to handle the union members the module itself defines, not your third union member. Continuing with your example where there are just two members of the union, module could could easily be doing `if (isOptionTypeA(optionType)) { /* ... */ } else { /* ... */ }`. Adding a third member makes the `else` branch problematic in that example.

Answer (score 3):

Type aliases don't merge like interfaces for example. There is no way to extend the union in another module. You can only define a union in your module and use that as needed.